# Post request is working in postman but not in ajax giving 405 method not found error

Tags: php

I am using localhost server with apache and mysql on xampp. I am implementing a login functionality for which php code is present in my api. When i make a POST request with POSTMAN result comes appropriately but when i make a ajax request i am getting 405 method not allowed error.

I think the headers are appropriately set but still i don't know why error is coming. I would highly appreciate if someone can point out why exactly is error coming and provide a solution code if possible.

this is my js code

````
```var sendRequest = function(formData) {

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                console.log("request sent succesfully..");
                return response;                  
                    }
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 401) {
                response = false;
                return response;
                    }

            }; 
    request.open("POST","../api/objects/user/login.php",true);
    request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.send(formData);
};```
````

this is my php code.

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
http://http://127.0.0.1:8080/login.html" );
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow- 
Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once '../../config/database.php';
include_once 'user.php';

//files for json web token
include_once '../../config/core.php';
include_once '../../libs/php-jwt-master/src/BeforeValidException.php';
include_once '../../libs/php-jwt-master/src/ExpiredException.php';
include_once '../../libs/php-jwt- 
master/src/SignatureInvalidException.php';
include_once '../../libs/php-jwt-master/src/JWT.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;


$db = new Database();
$conn = $db->getConnection();

$user = new User($conn);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$user->email = $data->email;

$email_exists = $user->emailExists();

if($email_exists && password_verify($data->password, $user->password))
{
$token = array(
"iss" => $iss,
"aud" => $aud,
"iat" => $iat,
"nbf" => $nbf,
"data" => array(
 "id" => $user->id,
 "firstname" => $user->firstname,
 "lastname" => $user->lastname,
 "email" => $user->email
 )
 );

http_response_code(200);

//generate JWT
$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);

echo json_encode(
 array(
     "message" => "Succesful Login",
     "jwt" => $jwt
)
);

}

else {
http_response_code(401);

echo json_encode(array("message" => "Login failed"));
}
?>
```

postman result on sending email and password as json

`{
   "message": "Succesful Login",
   "jwt": 
 "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJpYXQiOjEzNTY5OTk1MjQsIm5iZiI6MTM1NzAwMDAwMCwiZGF0YSI6eyJpZCI6IjIiLCJmaXJzdG5hbWUiOiJwcmFuYXYiLCJsYXN0bmFtZSI6ImFyb3JhIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhcm9yYS5wcmFuYXYuMjAwMEBnbWFpbC5jb20ifX0.npQWi4HP_QlGmmlkaPve3MBdn8u_yD_MxplUSKebNOY"
   }`

error shown by browser

`login.js:25 POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/objects/user/login.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)`